# Listen to a checkbox and show/hide circle-shape on google-maps (AngularJS)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

My question is related to this older thread [Google Maps v3 setting a circle with editable radius but not center](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11898108/google-maps-v3-setting-a-circle-with-editable-radius-but-not-center)

I had the same issue like this guy and solved my problem with the solution of geocodezip.

But now no stucked at another point. I have a checkbox called byRadius and only if this checkbox is marked I would like to show the circle. If not, I only want to show the marker. But I'm not able to find the circle or the marker in my HTML, so I'm not sure how I can change this visibility of the circle.

I used a listener on my checkbox to listen to the change-event and when fired i would like to change the visibility.

```
$scope.$watch('vm.socialMediaFilter.byRadius', function () 
{ 
  var circle = document.getElementById('circleModal');
  console.log(vm.socialMediaFilter.byRadius);
});
```

HTML-Tag of map

```
<div class="col-xs-12">
  <ng-map id="modalMap" class="gov-map" style="display: block; height: 25vh;"</ng-map>
</div>
```

[what got rendered from controller + html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mgnm5.png)

Comment: Is there any way for you to bind the object to `ng-model` in the DOM or directly to `$scope` instead of "looking it up" in the DOM with `document.getElementById('..')`?

Comment: the circle is not defined as a shape in my html. Because i needed to resize it without making it draggable i needed to draw it on my own without using the shape directive. the shape directive can make resizeable but it is by default not possible to make resizeable without making it draggable. i'm going to edit my post with the HTML. The functions that creates the shape and markers are the ones that you can find the linked thread

Comment: So why is it not possible to assign the object that you created in javascript to the `$scope`?

Comment: i put the circle element and also the radiusWidget in my $scope and changed my listener like this  `$scope.$watch('vm.socialMediaFilter.byRadius', function ()
        {
            if (vm.socialMediaFilter.byRadius) {
                $scope.circle.visible = false;
            } else $scope.circle.visible = true;
        });`But now I'm getting an exception that $scope is undefined at that moment.

Comment: If `$scope`is undefined, you most probably are outside of the controller's scope when adding the circle to `$scope`. Full code example of what you are doing would be beneficial.

Comment: hey anton, i have entered my full code as an answer to this post. hope you can help me

Answer (score 0):

```
(function () {
'use strict';

angular
    .module('kokosGisApp')
    .controller('SocialMediaFilterDialogController', SocialMediaFilterDialogController);

SocialMediaFilterDialogController.$inject = ['Principal', '$timeout', '$rootScope', '$scope', '$stateParams', '$uibModalInstance', 'entity', 'SocialMediaFilter', 'User', 'NgMap'];

function SocialMediaFilterDialogController(Principal, $timeout, $rootScope, $scope, $stateParams, $uibModalInstance, entity, SocialMediaFilter, User, NgMap) {
    var vm = this;
    vm.socialMediaFilter = entity;
    vm.clear = clear;
    vm.save = save;
    vm.users = User.query();

    if (vm.socialMediaFilter.mapInit == 0) {
        vm.socialMediaFilter.type = "Facebook";
        vm.socialMediaFilter.radius = 150;
        vm.socialMediaFilter.address = $rootScope.res[0];
        vm.socialMediaFilter.city = $rootScope.res[1];
        vm.socialMediaFilter.latitude = $rootScope.mouseEventLatLng.lat();
        vm.socialMediaFilter.longitude = $rootScope.mouseEventLatLng.lng();
    } else if (vm.socialMediaFilter.mapInit == 1) {
        vm.socialMediaFilter.type = "Facebook";
        vm.socialMediaFilter.radius = 150;
        vm.socialMediaFilter.address = '';
        vm.socialMediaFilter.city = '';
        vm.socialMediaFilter.latitude = 50.875863;
        vm.socialMediaFilter.longitude = 8.0168847;
    }


    Principal.identity().then(function (user) {
        vm.socialMediaFilter.user = user;
    });

    $timeout(function () {
        angular.element('.form-group:eq(1)>input').focus();
    });

    function clear() {
        $uibModalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
    }

    function save() {

        NgMap.getMap({id: 'modalMap'}).then(function (map) {
            if (typeof this.map.shapes !== 'undefined') {
                vm.socialMediaFilter.latitude = map.shapes.circleModal.center.lat();
                vm.socialMediaFilter.longitude = map.shapes.circleModal.center.lng();
                vm.socialMediaFilter.radius = map.shapes.circleModal.radius;
            } else {
                vm.socialMediaFilter.latitude = map.markers.markerModal.position.lat();
                vm.socialMediaFilter.longitude = map.markers.markerModal.position.lng();
                vm.socialMediaFilter.radius = null;
            }
        });
        vm.isSaving = true;
        if (vm.socialMediaFilter.id !== null) {
            SocialMediaFilter.update(vm.socialMediaFilter, onSaveSuccess, onSaveError);
        } else {
            SocialMediaFilter.save(vm.socialMediaFilter, onSaveSuccess, onSaveError);
        }
    }

    function onSaveSuccess(result) {
        $scope.$emit('kokosGisApp:socialMediaFilterUpdate', result);
        $uibModalInstance.close(result);
        vm.isSaving = false;
    }

    function onSaveError() {
        vm.isSaving = false;
    }

    $scope.$watch('vm.socialMediaFilter.byRadius', function ()
    {
        if (vm.socialMediaFilter.byRadius) {
            $scope.circle.visible = false;
        } else $scope.circle.visible = true;
    });

    /**
     * A distance widget that will display a circle that can be resized and will
     * provide the radius in km.
     *
     * @param {google.maps.Map} map The map to attach to.
     *
     * @constructor
     */

    function DistanceWidget(map) {
        this.set('map', map);
        this.set('position', map.getCenter());

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            // draggable: true,  // <-- change to make so position doesn't move
            title: 'Move me!',
            id: 'markerModal'
        });

        // Bind the marker map property to the DistanceWidget map property
        marker.bindTo('map', this);

        // Bind the marker position property to the DistanceWidget position
        // property
        marker.bindTo('position', this);

        // Create a new radius widget
        $scope.radiusWidget = new RadiusWidget();

        // Bind the radiusWidget map to the DistanceWidget map
        $scope.radiusWidget.bindTo('map', this);

        // Bind the radiusWidget center to the DistanceWidget position
        $scope.radiusWidget.bindTo('center', this, 'position');

        // Bind to the radiusWidgets' distance property
        this.bindTo('distance', $scope.radiusWidget);

        // Bind to the radiusWidgets' bounds property
        this.bindTo('bounds', $scope.radiusWidget);
    }

    DistanceWidget.prototype = new google.maps.MVCObject();


    /**
     * A radius widget that add a circle to a map and centers on a marker.
     *
     * @constructor
     */
    function RadiusWidget() {
        $scope.circle = new google.maps.Circle({
            strokeWeight: 2,
            color: 'orange',
            visible: true
        });

        // Set the distance property value, default to 10km.
        this.set('distance', 150);

        // Bind the RadiusWidget bounds property to the circle bounds property.
        this.bindTo('bounds', $scope.circle);

        // Bind the circle center to the RadiusWidget center property
        $scope.circle.bindTo('center', this);

        // Bind the circle map to the RadiusWidget map
        $scope.circle.bindTo('map', this);

        // Bind the circle radius property to the RadiusWidget radius property
        $scope.circle.bindTo('radius', this);

        // this.bindTo('byRadius', vm.socialMediaFilter.byRadius);

        // Add the sizer marker
        this.addSizer_();
    }

    RadiusWidget.prototype = new google.maps.MVCObject();
    // RadiusWidget.prototype.byRadius_changed = function () {
    //     console.log('dasdas');
    // }


    /**
     * Update the radius when the distance has changed.
     */
    RadiusWidget.prototype.distance_changed = function () {
        this.set('radius', this.get('distance'));
    };


    /**
     * Add the sizer marker to the map.
     *
     * @private
     */
    RadiusWidget.prototype.addSizer_ = function () {
        var sizer = new google.maps.Marker({
            draggable: true,
            visible: true
        });

        sizer.bindTo('map', this);
        sizer.bindTo('position', this, 'sizer_position');

        var me = this;
        google.maps.event.addListener(sizer, 'drag', function () {
            // As the sizer is being dragged, its position changes.  Because the
            // RadiusWidget's sizer_position is bound to the sizer's position, it will
            // change as well.
            var min = 0.5;
            var max = 2500;
            var pos = me.get('sizer_position');
            var center = me.get('center');
            var distance = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(center, pos);
            if (distance < min) {
                me.set('sizer_position', google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeOffset(center, min, google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeHeading(center, pos)));
            } else if (distance > max) {
                me.set('sizer_position', google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeOffset(center, max, google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeHeading(center, pos)));
            }
            // Set the circle distance (radius)
            me.setDistance();

        });
    };


    /**
     * Update the center of the circle and position the sizer back on the line.
     *
     * Position is bound to the DistanceWidget so this is expected to change when
     * the position of the distance widget is changed.
     */
    RadiusWidget.prototype.center_changed = function () {
        var bounds = this.get('bounds');

        // Bounds might not always be set so check that it exists first.
        if (bounds) {
            var lng = bounds.getNorthEast().lng();

            // Put the sizer at center, right on the circle.
            var position = new google.maps.LatLng(this.get('center').lat(), lng);
            this.set('sizer_position', position);
        }
    };


    /**
     * Set the distance of the circle based on the position of the sizer.
     */
    RadiusWidget.prototype.setDistance = function () {
        // As the sizer is being dragged, its position changes.  Because the
        // RadiusWidget's sizer_position is bound to the sizer's position, it will
        // change as well.
        var pos = this.get('sizer_position');
        var center = this.get('center');
        var distance = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(center, pos);

        // Set the distance property for any objects that are bound to it
        this.set('distance', distance);
    };


    function initMap() {

        NgMap.getMap({id:'modalMap'}).then(function (map) {
                map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(vm.socialMediaFilter.latitude, vm.socialMediaFilter.longitude));
                var currentCenter = map.getCenter();
                map.setZoom(15);
                google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
                map.setCenter(currentCenter);
                var distanceWidget = new DistanceWidget(map);

                // google.maps.event.addListener(distanceWidget, 'distance_changed', function () {
                //     displayInfo(distanceWidget);
                // });
                //
                // google.maps.event.addListener(distanceWidget, 'position_changed', function () {
                //     displayInfo(distanceWidget);
                // });
            }
        );

    }

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initMap());
}
})();
```

this is the controller that is used as a modal for saving an entity to my db

And i only would like to show the circle if the checkbox "Suchradius eingrenzen" is marked. If not marked I only would like to show the marker in the center.

[modal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/enweK.png)

Comment: okay...I had put that issue beside for a few days and tried to solve the problem today again. As far as i figured it out...the problem seems to be, that the RadiusWidget is private so I cannot use $scope. So now my new question is how I can make my $scope accessable inside of it?